# Ember testing with Objects that use third party scripts

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js, mocking, ember-cli, ember-testing

I wish to test some Ember Objects/Models which make use of a third party script for some calculations.

When I began writing these tests, I hit a problem when I started interacting with the third party scripts as they weren't loaded and I hit a bunch of undefined functions. I can get round it in this case by overriding the function in the test setup but this felt horrible.

Coming from a C# background I would normally use a mock/stub for the third party library and inject it as a depedency. During testing I would just check the mock was called correctly rather than testing the output.

I couldn't find a sensible example of this in Ember.

Would mocking the library be the most appropriate approach in Ember unit testing? and if that's the case, does anyone have a suggestion from a sensible mocking library I can use for Ember unit testing? I'm tied to an old version of Ember unfortunately for this project 1.7 (cli v 0.1.2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we are also using mocking practices. For example; creating a mock service, a mock util and even creating a mock config file...

For me, I'm not using an external library to mock objects. (By the way, as similar with you, I'm a java developer.) [As written in the guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/testing/testing-components/#toc_stubbing-services), I do stubbing of the needed object.

You can have a look at other answers at Stackoverflow about stubbing: [stubbing store at component tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40095062/4545506), [stubbing store at instance initializer tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36731207/instance-initializer-unit-test-fails-with-store-is-undefined/36912845#36912845)...

Your idea of mocking is totally valid and reasonable. If you want further research, you can have a look at *mocking tools* section of the [qunit's plugins](https://qunitjs.com/plugins/).